# packaging directory in php

Tags: php, linux, zip

I pack directory tree

```
system('zip -r -0   '.$file_arch.' /var/www/catalog/catalog_user/xml/1/ ');
```

It works, but I unpack the full path to all subfolders, and I want to pack only what is in the directory

the params -j does not work ..

Comment: Then `chdir` to the target directory first, and specify the absolute path of the output zip file instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the `-r` see http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_zip.htm

-r stand for recursive, and will include all subfolders.

Or change to:

```
system('cd /var/www/catalog/catalog_user/xml/1/ && zip -r -0   '.$file_arch.' . ');
```

to store without the whole path.

Comment: generally does not create zip files :(